# Install and deploy oracle Bi publisher

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, ear, bi-publisher

Just a very very simple question :

Is there any way to install and deploy **oracle bi publisher 12c** module on weblogic **without** download and install the whole of ORACLE BI 12C .
I want just the oracle bi publisher not whole of ORACLE BI .
Thank you .

Comment: as this [Oracle Document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12096_01/books/PubDeploy/install.htm), you need first ( Java Runtime Environment (JRE) / Java Development Kit (JDK) version 1.4 or later, Any J2EE-based application server, Database, Web Browser) and the rest is easy and discussed properly in the link.

Comment: Yes But this is for oracle 10G !  Not for  12c

Comment: In oracle BI publisher 10g you can deploy it on apache tomcat too . But in 12c we have a huge module(ORACLE BI) that consist of lower modules like bi publisher 12 c . I want to know is there any way to deploy and use BI publisher without that huge module !